Using Blender 3DS export then import, why are all my objects misarranged?
I'm using the Autodesk 3DS blender add-on to export and import 3ds files. Why is it that when I export the 3Ds file when it looks like this: 
Then when I open a new blend file and import the same 3ds model i just exported, it will all be separated and look like this: 
These are my settings at export: 
Please let me know if you may need more info to answer my question

There's a Wiki page about that addon here which might help.
